# Category Link Not Showing Up

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cms

I've added a category link widget (as below) to my homepage. The link does not display on the frontend though.

`{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link" anchor_text="Shop Caps" title="Show Caps" template="category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/2"}}`

I have performed the following:

- Created category `Caps`.
- Created a test product and assigned it to `Caps`.
- Created the widget on the page and saved.
- Cleared `var/cache` and `var/page_cache`.

Other CMS changes on the homepage display, and other widgets (such as a product list) display. It seems to be this singular widget type that won't display.